# Cookie deleted in conditional GET request

Tags: asp.net, azure, cookies, fiddler, sitefinity

Recently our website hosted on Azure encountered a strange problem. After logging in, the user's immediately unauthenticated, and when they click on any link to go to other page, they will be redirected to login page due to unauthenticated. It doesn't happen all the time, but the consequence is serious, because we don't even know when it happens, there's no exception to log, just suddenly lost of authentication
Yesterday I encountered this issue on production, and captured the requests sequence during the time I got kicked out using Fiddler, and find something unusual:

[image: Fiddler captured]

The page I landed after login in /my-quizzes (colored in green). When I click on a link to go to different page ("/group" link, with green color), I'm redirected to sign in page. Between my requests to /my-quizzes and /group, there are some other requests for javascript, images, etc. The strange thing is in the highlighted request for "uncheckCheckBox.png", in the response, the authentication cookie (.SFAUTH-XXX) and some other cookies are deleted (set to empty string, with expiry date = 12/10/1999). This is the reason that subsequent request to /group page is unauthenticated

Our website is built on top of Sitefinity, using ASP.NET MVC

My questions are:

- Is it normal to have cookies deleted in an image request like this? And this is just a conditional GET to check whether the image is modified, which is quite unusual to me. But I cannot explain why it happens
- Any suggestion on how we can debug this issue of cookies deleted?

Answer (score 0):

How many instances of Azure is your site running on?
If more than one - do you have the Sitefinity Load Balancing module configured?

It is possible that when you click on the /Group page link the request goes to another Azure instance where you are not authenticated (because of a misconfigured LB for instance).

Do you have your app pool recycling on regular intervals? That could be another reason too.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. We use Sitefinity on Azure, and from Sitefinity's documentation, we don't need to configure Sitefinity load balancing, because Sitefinity will use Azure API for load balancing (http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/sitefinity-azure-configuration). We disable most of the settings in app pool that possibly affect recyling like request limit, memory limit, etc. But we do have setting for regular recycling (1740 mins, which is every 29 hours). But the session storage is using Azure cache, so this recycling should not be an issue right?

Comment: Yes, Sitefinity handles load balancing automatically if you are using Azure Cloud Services. If you are on Azure VMs or Web Sites - then this is not automatic.
I don't think it is a good idea to have regular recycling of the App pool on a production environment. Makes no sense to me.